# Wrapping List.Add() gives - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, runtime-error, nullreferenceexception

I want to wrap `List` class with my custom class. As for now I have something like this ;

```
public class PriorityListOfNodes
{

    private List<Node>          list_;
    private IComparer<Node>     sorter_;

    public List<Node> List_ {
            get {return list_;}
            set {list_ = value;}
    }

    public PriorityListOfNodes ()
    {
            sorter_ = new NodeSorter_fValueDescending ();
    }

    public Node PopFromEnd ()
    {
            Node temp = new Node (list_ [list_.Count - 1]);
            list_.RemoveAt (list_.Count - 1);
            return temp;
    }

    public Node PeekFromEnd ()
    {
            return list_ [list_.Count - 1];
    }

    public void Add (ref Node toAdd)
    {
            Debug.Log (toAdd);
            list_.Add (toAdd);
            list_.Sort (sorter_);
    }
}
```

When I do now

```
Node temp = new Node(10,20); //custom constructor
PriorityListOfNodes l = new PriorityListOfNodes();
l.add(temp);
```

I get runtime exception :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I have also tried without `ref` but with the same result. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Very strange naming style.. usually private fields have underscore prefix, or they don't have any prefix

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I used to used prefixes but it takes longer to write (you finish the word autocomplete).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never actually instantiate a `List<Node>`.

```
 public PriorityListOfNodes ()
    {
            sorter_ = new NodeSorter_fValueDescending ();
            list_ = new List<Node>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, classes have empty parameterless constructors, so you effectively have:

```
public class PriorityListOfNodes
{
    private List<Node> list_;
    // ...

    public PriorityListOfNodes()
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

When you later call `Add` your list is declared, but not initialised. You need to do this at some point, probably in the constructor:

```
public class PriorityListOfNodes
{
    private List<Node> list_;
    // ...

    public PriorityListOfNodes()
    {
         this.list_ = new List<Node>();
         // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

See [Using Constructors (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).